# SharePoint 2010 Workflows - Is it possible to call rest api

Tags: workflow

So here is my situation,  I am working in a SharePoint 2013 Environment, but they only have SHarePoint 2010 Workflows enabled.   I see lots of questions and blogs that describe making rest api calls in workflows.  Yet, when I attempt to do the same things I do not see the same options.  So I am hopeful, maybe there is a 2010 way of getting around that.

Direct Question:
Is it possible to make rest api calls in SharePoint 2010 Workflows?
if so, please show me your secret sauce.

End Goal:  I want to setup reports that pull from several lists and email those to Management.   I currently do this with a Powershell script that calls rest api , then emails the report. I want to automate this process.  But I am a user, I dont have access to servers and can't setup timer jobs.  So I am trying to figure out some other way to accomplish the same thing to run on a monthly basis, without me having to push the button or manually run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to make rest api calls in SharePoint 2010 Workflows?

No. That feature was introduced with SPD 2013 workflows.

> So I am trying to figure out some other way to accomplish the same thing to run on a monthly basis, without me having to push the button or manually run it.

Do you have access to a PC or server that is always turned when you need this update to occur? You use a PowerShell Scheduled Job to auto-run your update. You can either complete the email task from PowerShell, or you can have PowerShell do the REST requests and save the data needed for the emails to a SharePoint list, and let a 2010 workflow trigger from those changes.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introduction-to-powershell-scheduled-jobs/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Ok,  I was able to setup a timer job and run the script.  That worked well for the most part.